# Не получаю ответ с сервера ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-form

Отправляю html form через ajax. На сервере проверяю поля на валидность и отправляю ответ. В success обрабатываю ответ. 
Но почему-то всегда попадаю на error

form.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['do_register'])) {

    $errors = array ();
    $arrayFields = array (
        'name' => $_REQUEST['name'],
        'email' => $_REQUEST['email'],
        'password' => $_REQUEST['password'],
        'password2' => $_REQUEST['password2']
    );

    foreach ($arrayFields as $fieldName => $oneField) {
        if ($oneField == '' || !isset($oneField)){
                $errors[$fieldName] = 'Required field';
        }
    }

    if (!filter_var($arrayFields['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $errors['email'] = 'Email is incorrect';

    if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['name']) < 4)
            $errors['name'] = 'Name must be more than 4 characters';

    if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['password']) < 6) {

        $errors['password'] = 'Password must be more than 6 characters';
    } else
    if ($arrayFields['password'] != $arrayFields['password2'])
        $errors['password2'] = 'Passwords do not match';

    if (empty($errors)) {

        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
    } else {

        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'text_error' => $errors));
    }
}
```

form.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        // убираем класс ошибок с инпутов
        $('input').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('error_input');
        });
        // прячем текст ошибок
        $('.error').hide();

        // получение данных из полей
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var password2 = $('#password2').val();

        console.log(name)
        console.log(email)
        console.log(password)
        console.log(password2)
        $.ajax({
            // метод отправки
            type: "POST",
            // путь до скрипта-обработчика
            url: "form.php",
            // какие данные будут переданы
            data: {
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'password': password,
                'password2': password2
            },
            // тип передачи данных
            dataType: "json",
            // действие, при ответе с сервера
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data.result);
                // в случае, когда пришло success. Отработало без ошибок
                if(data.result == 'success'){
                    console.log(data.result);
                    alert('User successfully registered');
                    // в случае ошибок в форме
                } else {
                    // перебираем массив с ошибками
                    console.log(data);
                    for(var errorField in data.text_error){
                        // выводим текст ошибок
                        $('#'+errorField+'_error').html(data.text_error[errorField]);
                        console.log('sdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsds');
                        // показываем текст ошибок
                        $('#'+errorField+'_error').show();
                        // обводим инпуты красным цветом
                        $('#'+errorField).addClass('error_input');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
        // останавливаем сабмит, чтоб не перезагружалась страница
        return false;
    });
});
```

index.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="op">
                    <form name="myForm" class="formBorder" method="POST" id="form" novalidate>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h3>Register</h3>

                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                            <label id="email_error" class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
                            <label id="name_error" class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password(at least 6 characters)" required>
                            <label id="password_error" class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password2">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm the password" required>
                            <label id="password2_error" class="error"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__group">
                            <button type="submit" value="Send" name="do_register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (filter_var($arrayFields['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Это условие будет всегда срабатывать и давать ошибку при корректном имейле..

Смените на:

```
if ( !filter_var($arrayFields['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
```

Ну, и тут:

```
if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['password']) < 6) {

    $errors['name'] = 'Password must be more than 4 characters';
```

Проверка для `$arrayFields['password']` а ошибку записываем в `$errors['name']`, да и в условии 6 символов, а в тексте 4 только. Не помешает исправить

Comment: Проблема не в самой валидации, а в том, что в ajax всегда попадаю на error, т.е ответа с сервера не приходит, в аналагичном проекте всё работает

Comment: Но, тем не менее это не отменяет тех ошибок что я описал, из-за них так же ошибочно скрипт работает.

Comment: Запрос в консоли идёт на верный адрес? Если да - проверьте возвращаемый json на валидность или попробуйте сменить `dataType`

Comment: Сменил на html и попал в success, но data пришла совсем непонятно откуда.
Я пока только изучаю всё это и не особо понимаю как всё работает.

Comment: Вот такой json я получаю 

{"result":"error","text_error":{"name":"Name must be more than 4 characters","email":"Email is incorrect","password":"Password must be more than 6 characters","password2":"Required field"}}

Comment: Но в если ставлю dataType: "json", то data оказывается пустой

Comment: смените в php обработчике `$_REQUEST` на `$_POST` в условии `if(isset(...))` и `$arrayFields=...`

Comment: Не помогло, всё еще попадаю в error

Comment: @Ringo как у вас работает ваш код, если вы делаете проверку на `do_register`, но в свою очередь не передаете этот параметр?

Comment: <button type="submit" value="Send" name="do_register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

Comment: Вот тут например